# XSLT - set a condition in template to execute only once for sub sequent nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to XLST, posting my question after searching for help in this portal.

I have a typical scenario where I need to transform XML into target XML as blocks per status at record node level below.
But the Header `<eventName>` and `<eventdate>` should present only once in first block of section in my target file.

I’m using nested for loop on Header in that another loop on record to scan each status code. Once I find status code is !=’00’ then calling a template.

How do I check or set a condition with in template to execute only once for subsequent calls on template?

Tried with a param that var defined in top loop with value assigned position() but it did not work as record level it would remain same.

Please advise a solution.
An example input XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<n0:example>
    <eventName>Managers Event</eventName>
    <eventdate>09292016</eventdate>
    <header>
        <status>01</status>
        <SubHead>
            <Record>
                <status>10</status>
                <Service>Food</Service>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <status>00</status>
                <Service>Music</Service>
            </Record>
        </SubHead>
    </header>
    <header>
        <status>02</status>
        <SubHead>
            <Record>
                <status>11</status>
                <Service>Food</Service>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <status>00</status>
                <Service>Music</Service>
            </Record>
        </SubHead>
    </header>
</n0:example>
```

Comment: Usually just trying to rethink your approach helps in XSLT. Assume the tags are events and you cannot pass information between them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your attempted stylesheet and the expected output. -- Note also that the input is not well-formed XML: the `ns0` prefix is not bound to a namespace